# pyperclip.copy(str(line)) not copying properly

Tags: python, pyautogui, pyperclip

Im trying to get paths in a list.txt, one per line, then copy a line and paste in a program prompt, but it keeps me saying "file not found", if I paste the copied line in a notepad, then copy/paste with the mouse the text in notepad into the prompt program, it works. I dont know if there is some hidden instruction in pyperclip.copy that is doing this failure. I cant use `pyautogui.typewrite(line)` becouse my folders have accents and `typewrite` mess with then.

```
ProjectFile = io.open('D:\master\list.txt', 'r',encoding="utf8")
lines = ProjectFile.readlines()  
        
for line in lines: 
                   
#pyautogui.typewrite(line) 

print(line)
pyperclip.copy(str(line))
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
          
ProjectFile.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just got it, have to remove the breakline.

```
 pyperclip.copy((str(line)).replace("\n", ""))
```